# Apply color management only to scene and not to background image? (Mix color management false color and filmic)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, color-management

I am currently working on a video and I stumbled upon the color management section of the render properties. I really like the look of the "false color" view transform so I want to use it as I really like the vibrant colors.

At the moment I have my scene (foreground) and a background image attached to the camera (its a png of clouds i drew in photoshop).

This is the background image:

[image]

I want the scene to use the "false color" view transform and the background image attached to the camera use the normal filmic view transform.
Is this possible?

These are my compositing nodes so far. The top image is the background and the one on the bottom is the "scene" with the flowers and grass. In the small preview windows you can see that currently **both** are using the "false color" view transform.

[image: screenshot of my compositing nodes]

These are the color management view transforms I use:

[image: color management view transforms]

I only want those to be applied to the foreground and not to the background image so that the final render will look like this:

[image: rendered viewport preview]

Is this possible? Can I somehow mix two types of color management styles/ apply color management only to a scene and not the attached background?

Comment: Hmm. Since the color management at hand is in the render properties, not likely that is separable there. If you can find a similar color management equivalent for the layers/compositor, you’re good to go.

Comment: The problem with view transforms is that they make it impossible to determine what the final colors will be, whereas if you use Standard view transform, the colors you set are the colors you will get

Comment: I can see the problem. I might try what Robin Betts proposed. It looks like a good workaround plus more controllable.

However I wonder if its possible because in my render view I got both images rendered separately. Background and Foreground seem to be blended afterwards. Maybe a Photoshop script that adds the fixed background to every single frame would be an extremely tedious workaround but possible. Obviously I'd prefer a solution inside of blender.

Answer (score 2):

*False Color* converts image intensity to hue.

How about giving your objects a home-made 'False Color' material?

[image]

(EEVEE render only)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I will definitely try that. What I liked about the false color view transform is that it changes with the lighting which produces more complex patterns. 
But thats a good solution if all else fails.

Comment: Hi @softcake! This changes with lighting, too. That's the point :)

Comment: Yes I literally just realized that lying in bed thinking about the project and solutions... Had to get up again to answer your reply again.
Thanks so much for the solution!